# XPath nodes come after new line

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am trying to get the node text for the nodes that have div align center:
`

```
                <tr> 
                  <td width="39" class="back1"><b class="texto4">CRN</b></td>
                  <td width="60" class="back1"><b class="texto4">Materia</b></td>
                  <td width="53" class="back1"><b class="texto4">Secci&oacute;n</b></td>
                  <td width="55" class="back1"><b class="texto4">Cr&eacute;ditos</b></td>
                  <td width="156" class="back1"><b class="texto4">T&iacute;tulo</b></td>
                  <td width="69" class="back1"><b class="texto4">Cupo</b></td>
                  <td width="57" class="back1"><b class="texto4">Inscritos</b></td>
                  <td width="77" class="back1"><b class="texto4">Disponible</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                  <td width="39"><font class="texto4"> 
                    10110                        </font></td>
                  <td width="60"><font class="texto4"> 
                    IIND1000                        </font></td>
                  <td width="53"><font class="texto4"> 
                  <div align="center">
                    1                        </div></font></td>
                  <td width="55"><font class="texto4"> 
                    <div align="center">
                    3                       </div>
                    </font></td>
                  <td width="156"><font class="texto4"> 
                    INTROD. INGEN. INDUSTRIAL                        </font></td>
                  <td width="69"><font class="texto4"> 
                    100                        </font></td>
                  <td width="57"><font class="texto4"> 
                    100                        </font></td>
                  <td width="77"><font class="texto4"> 
                    0                        </font></td>
                </tr>
              </table> `
```

The problem is JTidy doesn't get the text in that child node because (I'm assuming here) there's a new line between `<font class="texto4">` and `<div align="center">`. The output when I get the every element under that node inside a List and print it is empty.

My XPathExpression so far is `expr = xpath.compile("//td[@width='55']/font/div/text()");` (or width='69', for the other node).

My full code attempt is:

```
String cod = "IIND2401";
    String dep = cod.substring(0, 4);
    System.out.println(dep);
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://registroapps.uniandes.edu.co/scripts/adm_con_horario1_joomla.php?depto="+dep);
        Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
        tidy.setXHTML(true);    
        Document doc = tidy.parseDOM(url.openStream(), System.out);

        // Use XPath to obtain whatever you want from the (X)HTML
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//td[@width='39']/font/text()");
        NodeList crn = (NodeList)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Then I take those codes I obtain, put them in a List and print them:

```
List<String> crns = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < crn.getLength(); i++) {
            crns.add(crn.item(i).getNodeValue()); 
        }
```

System.out.println("CRNs:");
            System.out.println(crns);

The result is a long list of IDs for courses in my university for the IIND faculty.
CRNs:
[10110, 16886, 12420, 12526, 12527, 12528, 13510, 15146, 12544, 12545,(...)]
I can't change the HTML document, I'm trying to parse this off of my University's website. Any advice? Thanks guys.

Comment: Use [String.trim() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim())

Comment: Newline is just text, in XML. That isn't your problem unless JTidy is doing something odd. Are you sure the document doesn't use namespaces?

Comment: @gerrytan I can't, since Jtidy is doing all the XML parsing. I would have to read the XML line by line and modify the lines that bother me, which would be rather inefficient (some are 10k+ lines)

Comment: @keshlam I'm pretty sure it doesn't. I just don't get why it stops working only with those lines. Is my Xpath Expression correct?