# XPath Expression with Jsoup

Tags: java, xpath, html-parsing, jsoup

Need help with this expression

```
"//tr[td[normalize-space(font) = '"+params[1]+"']]/td/font/text()"
```

I'm trying to get the information out of this HTML document

```
<table width="575" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
    <tr> 
      <td width="39" class="back1"><b class="texto4">CRN</b></td>
      <td width="60" class="back1"><b class="texto4">Materia</b></td>
      <td width="53" class="back1"><b class="texto4">Secci&oacute;n</b></td>
      <td width="55" class="back1"><b class="texto4">Cr&eacute;ditos</b></td>
      <td width="156" class="back1"><b class="texto4">T&iacute;tulo</b></td>
      <td width="69" class="back1"><b class="texto4">Cupo</b></td>
      <td width="57" class="back1"><b class="texto4">Inscritos</b></td>
      <td width="77" class="back1"><b class="texto4">Disponible</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td width="39"><font class="texto4"> 
        10110                        </font></td>
      <td width="60"><font class="texto4"> 
        IIND1000                        </font></td>
      <td width="53"><font class="texto4"> 
      <div align="center">
        1                        </div></font></td>
      <td width="55"><font class="texto4"> 
        <div align="center">
        3                       </div>
        </font></td>
      <td width="156"><font class="texto4"> 
        INTROD. INGEN. INDUSTRIAL                        </font></td>
      <td width="69"><font class="texto4"> 
        100                        </font></td>
      <td width="57"><font class="texto4"> 
        100                        </font></td>
      <td width="77"><font class="texto4"> 
        0                        </font></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If I look for params1=10110, I want to get every td element within that tr tag (10110,IIND1000, 1, 3, INTROD. INGEN. INDUSTRIAL, 100, 100, 0).

Jtidy wasn't really doing the job well ([it was having trouble with the spaces between font and div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24668436/xpath-nodes-come-after-new-line)), so I decided to use Jsoup instead. Would anyone happen to know how to convert that Xpath Expression at the beginning so it can be used in Jsoup?

So far I've managed to get this expression: `font.texto4:contains(10110)`, which gets only "10110". I haven't found a way, however, to get the text from every child node on its same level.

EDTI: I'm a noob at Jsoup, but I'm trying out more expressions and checking the result. I found that if I try this expression `tr>td:contains(10110) font.texto4`, I get the text for EVERY element in the table. I just want to narrow it down to the set of tr nodes in the same level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be done in both xpath and jsoup way. Consider this example.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class SibilingParse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
                String html = "<table width='575' border='0' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='0'>"
                                + "<tr>"
                                    + "<td width='39'><font class='texto4'>10110</font></td>"
                                    + "<td width='60'><font class='texto4'>IIND1000</font></td>"
                                    + "<td width='53'><font class='texto4'><div align='center'>1</div></font></td>"
                                    + "<td width='55'><font class='texto4'><div align='center'>3</div></font></td>"
                                    + "<td width='156'><font class='texto4'>INTROD. INGEN. INDUSTRIAL</font></td>"
                                    + "<td width='69'><font class='texto4'>100</font></td>"
                                    + "<td width='57'><font class='texto4'>100</font></td>"
                                    + "<td width='77'><font class='texto4'>0</font></td>"
                                + "</tr>"
                            + "</table>";

                //Xpath way
                System.out.println("XPATH");
                InputStream xmlStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes());
                DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(xmlStream);
                XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

                String expression = "/table/tr/td//*[text()='10110']//../following-sibling::td";
                NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getTextContent()); 
                }
                System.out.println();

                // Jsoup way
                org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
                Elements tds = doc.select("td:contains(10110)");
                if(tds != null && tds.size() > 0){
                    for(Element td : tds.first().siblingElements()){
                        System.out.println(td.text());
                    }
                }
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

}
```

**Based on Url**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class SiblingJsoup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup
                    .connect("http://registroapps.uniandes.edu.co/scripts/adm_con_horario1_joomla.php?depto=IIND")
                    .timeout(20000)
                    .get();

            Elements tds = doc.select("font:containsOwn(10110)");
            if (tds != null && tds.size() > 0) {
                for (Element td : tds.parents().first().siblingElements()) {
                    System.out.println(td.text());
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Great idea! I get a NPE on this line, however: doc.select("td:contains(10110)").first().siblingElements(), more specifically on .siblingElements(). I'm parsing the document directly from a URL this time, not from HTML code as you did. Could this be the problem? (the URL loads without issues in my browser)

Comment: That is because there isn't any td with 10110. So `first()` would be null and i'm invoking siblingElements on null. I should have done some null or length checks. I just put that as an example.. :)

Comment: Updated my answer. Now it should be ok.. :)

Comment: I have a feeling your answer solves my problems, but still it doesn't work. It doesn't print anything, even if there isn't a NPE now.

Comment: It doesn't even enter the loop, so the elements might just be empty.

Comment: Check whether you have a td with value 10110. Else if possible please share the url. :)

Comment: http://registroapps.uniandes.edu.co/scripts/adm_con_horario1_joomla.php?depto=IIND

Comment: Done. That was because of the parent td. When we say `td:contains` it search on child td as well. There is a method to `containsOwn` to check for own text. Since td doesn't have that id and font field has that we need to do `contains` or `containsOwn` on the font field. Updated my answer.

Comment: Wow, it takes it a while (which I assume is the server's fault), but it works! Thanks man.

Comment: Yes. Even in browser the server is slow. That is why I gave that timeout